# ERC721A Error in Remix

Tags: remix, nft, erc-721

Good morning! Remix IDE is detecting an error in the ERC721A contract.Someone with the same problem? Is compiling but show that has 4 error in the next functions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any solution?? Or I should ignore this error? Thanks!